# Is there a way to highligt strings in a UWP WebView?

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp

Is there a way to highligt a string inside a page in a UWP WebView?

My goal is to replicate the "Find In Page" feature seen in a lot of morden web browsers.

I tried using the `window.find()` javaScript method by using `webView.InvokeScriptAsync` in C#, but it throws me an User Handled Exception :System.Exception:
**'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101'**

Edit:
Here is some code:

xaml.cs:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "window.find(\"test string\")" });
}
```

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Text="Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <WebView x:Name="webView1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You could make use of a [`SelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), this won't require user interaction when invoked.

Comment: Could you please provide us your code sample for testing?